# How to Configure AzureDevops to commit only on specific branch in Code Commit

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have Repository on AzureDevops, and i'm mirroring it to CodeCommit.

The PowerShell Script that I'm using right now is:

```
$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'
git clone --mirror https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MelonElevenPoint2/ThrottleUp/_git/ThrottleUp_Mobile
cd ThrottleUp_Mobile.git
git push --force --all https://$(user):$(pass)@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/ThrottleUp
```

As of now, when I push on the develop branch, I build full repo on Code Commit. This needs to be changed, example:
On push to develop branch, I need to build only develop branch on Code Commit

I have created similar script but id does not work:

```
$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'
git clone --mirror https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MelonElevenPoint2/ThrottleUp/_git/ThrottleUp_Mobile
cd ThrottleUp_Mobile.git
git push origin develop https://$(user):$(pass)@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/ThrottleUp
```

I'm getting this kind of error: `fatal: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs`

Any help?

Comment: The mirror clone presumably has `remote.origin.mirror` set to `true`. This presumably makes the `git push` fail. I'm not sure that the `git push` is *supposed* to fail here, but if you like, you can run `git config --unset remote.origin.mirror` after the clone step, before the `git push`. Or, after verifying that it's `git push` that complains here, report this as a Git bug, if you think only a *command line* `--mirror` should produce this fatal error. (I'm not sure one way or the other.)